# UserForm.Multipage.Pages, Page class in two libraries

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I am working on a userform trying to loop through the controls in a multipage.

The user form has 2 Multipages (MultiPage1 and MultiPage2).

Multipage2 is contained within the Multipage1.

When only MultiPage1 exists I could ran the following code:

```
For Each pPage In frmValidationTest.MultiPage1.Pages
```

But after creating this nested system, and I trying to run it again, displays the following error:

"Type Mismatch" (in the For Each pPage line)

The variable pPages is declared as follows:

```
Dim pPage as Page
```

I've ran Debug.Print Mode to check misspelling issues but everything is OK ("frmValidationTest.MultiPage1.Pages.Name" does actually print out an output)

When I take a look at the pPages, it declares that the variable is Nothing.

I just realized that when declaring the variable, I have 2 classes with the same name "Page".[image]

Not sure what's going on, is that normal? I don't think I should have 2 different classes for the same superclass. (-F2- Ref Lib only shows 1).

After closing, restarting, etc. The issue still there.

Hopefully is just a minor thing!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Page` class in both the `Excel` and `MSForms` libraries. So you will be better off using the library names in your declarations. For example, if your form looks like this:

[image]

Then this code should work:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ' declare variables using specific libraries
    Dim mpgItem1 As MSForms.MultiPage
    Dim mpgItem2 As MSForms.MultiPage
    Dim pagItem1 As MSForms.Page
    Dim pagItem2 As MSForms.Page
    ' other variables
    Dim ctlItem As Control
    Dim intCounter1 As Integer
    Dim intCounter2 As Integer
    Dim intPageCount1 As Integer
    Dim intPageCount2 As Integer

    Set mpgItem1 = UserForm1.MultiPage1
    ' get page count of first multi page
    intPageCount1 = mpgItem1.Pages.Count

    ' not using for..each loop ...
    For intCounter1 = 0 To intPageCount1 - 1
        Set pagItem1 = mpgItem1.Pages(intCounter1)
        MsgBox pagItem1.Name
        For Each ctlItem In pagItem1.Controls
            ' looking for nested multi page
            If TypeName(ctlItem) = "MultiPage" Then
                ' same code as for first multipage
                Set mpgItem2 = ctlItem
                intPageCount2 = mpgItem2.Pages.Count
                For intCounter2 = 0 To intPageCount2 - 1
                    Set pagItem2 = mpgItem2.Pages(intCounter2)
                    MsgBox pagItem2.Name
                Next intCounter2
            End If
        Next ctlItem
    Next intCounter1

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks #Robin :)
As usually, simple solution and something new to learn!
Everything is working smoothly now!